# Save variable extracted with Regex Extractor in Simple Data Writer

Tags: regex, jmeter

Is this possible? 
I am extracting part of a JSON response and want to save them all via the Simple Data Writer.

As far as I have researched this does not seem to be possible.

Regex: “cost”:(.+?)

Should be capturing things like

"cost":1.99

Answer (score 1):

I figured out why..

In the jmeter.properties you need to include the variable name as

sample_variables=ExtractedCost

I thought calling it cost_variable=ExtractCost would be fine. Apparently not. That said, my regex is still wrong as it doesn't come up with anything. That should be easier to figure out

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your `"cost":(.+?)` will return something like `1` and everything after dot will be discarded.

I would suggest to amend your regex as follows:

- Regular Expression: `"cost":(.*)`
- Template: `$1$`

See [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65150-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jm) for more info on regular expressions.